# Can anyone help me with this contradicting graphs?

Tags: analytic-geometry

While studying SAT MATH 2 , I tried to solve the following problem but faced some difficulty. The problem goes ........

In the graph of the parametric equations  $x= t^2+t$   , $y=t^2-t$

A) $x\ge 0$

B) $x\ge -\frac{1}{4}$

The answer given in the book is as follows 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8VKUxBBIaO2LTJlb1lTalcxQ1k/view?usp=sharing

Here starts the problem. When I graph the given parametric equations, my graph does not extend to the left of zero. According to the graph I obtained, the answer should be $x\ge0$. Here is a pic of the graph I obtained
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8VKUxBBIaO2YzY0VVhrVFp6U2c/view?usp=sharing

So, I hereby kindly request someone to help me with this issue

Comment: What happens to your graph when $t=-0.1$?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8VKUxBBIaO2YzY0VVhrVFp6U2c/view ...There is no graph for x<0

Comment: What do you mean? $x$ is given by the formula, $x=t^2+t$. What happens when $t=-0.1$?

Comment: -0.09 .      This is what I get when I substitute in the eq for x

Comment: So, doesn't that tell you that there **is** a graph for $x<0$? Doesn't it tell you that the point $(-0.09,0.11)$ is on the graph?

Comment: Then why doesnt it show in my graph ?

Comment: Presumably because you made some mistake when you drew your graph. Since I don't know how you drew your graph, I can't tell you why it doesn't show in your graph. But you do agree that it's there, right?

Comment: This is what I entered to get the graph ... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8VKUxBBIaO2aUFvMWFyMUV6eHc ... Whats the fault now?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to ask someone who knows something about that kind of calculator.

Answer (score 0):

the command "ParametricPlot[{t^2+t,t^2-t},{t,-1,1}]" shows the parabola like in your exercise book

Comment: My graphic calculator is fx 9860 ... so I selected graph mode , changed the type of parametric and type x1 and y1 repect ..... So what should I do now ?

Comment: you must select parametric plot